# std::streambuf::in_aval always returns 0 for std::ostream

Tags: c++, stl, streambuf

My goal is to get data stored in `streambuf`. My idea is getting `streambuf` by `rdbuf` and then getting data using `sgetn`.

```
class mystreambuf : public std::streambuf {}

mystreambuf strbuf;
std::ostream os(&strbuf);
os << "1234567890";
std::streambuf *sb = os.rdbuf();
std::streamsize size = sb->in_avail();
```

I expected to get 10 but I get 0 returned from `in_avail` method.

Comment: Why would an output stream have input available?

Answer (score 0):

In order to access data stored in a [std::streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/streambuf/streambuf/), you can link the [std::ostream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) to a [std::stringbuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringbuf/) and get its content using `std::stringbuf::str()`

```
std::stringbuf strbuf;
std::ostream os(&strbuf);  
os << "1234567890";

std::string content(strbuf.str());
std::cout << "size: " << content.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "content: " << content << std::endl;
```

This will give :

> size: 10
>   content: 0123456789

A shorter way is to use a [std::stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/ostringstream/)

```
std::ostringstream os;  
os << "1234567890";

std::string content(os.str());
std::cout << "size: " << content.size() << std::endl;
std::cout << "content: " << content << std::endl;
```